# LWJGL 3 change OpenGL context / ContextAttribs alternative

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

In LWJGL 2 I could to use a older profile of OpenGL do that:

```
PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
ContextAttribs contextAtrributes = new ContextAttribs(3, 2) //<--
            .withProfileCore(true)
            .withForwardCompatible(true);

Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
Display.setTitle(WINDOW_TITLE);
Display.create(pixelFormat, contextAtrributes);
```

In LWJGL 3 there is no Display class anymore, how can I do it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`glfwWindowHint`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwWindowHint(int,%20int)) for the `ContextAttribs`:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
```

Then

```
glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, 0, 0)
```

`glfwWindowHint` can also change the options found in [`PixelFormat`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat.html), and the defaults are different so you may want to.

You will also need to call `glfwInit()` before all of this.

More complete guide can be found here: http://www.lwjgl.org/guide